# Service or BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

First time I have tried to implement either of these and I am unsure which to use.

I want my application to create a time frame, e.g. 2/3/12 to 7/3/12.  Multiple time frames such as this can be created.  A different intervals (e.g. every 4 hours) I would like my application to preform some actions for each time frame.  This needs to be done in the background.

I have first tried to implement this with a Service, but am having performing all the actions for each of the time frames concurrently.  After reading the android blog "Multitasking the android way" I think that perhaps BroadcastReceivers are better.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my answer about using the AlarmManager -  [Running task periodicaly(once a day/once a week)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615543/running-task-periodicalyonce-a-day-once-a-week/8615600#8615600)

If you are only running a process at a set time rather than constantly (e.g. monitoring audio levels) then you are going to ask a service to sit there 90% of the time and do nothing except waste battery power. The AlarmManager solves this problem as it notifies the broadcast receiver to execute at the given times.

Edit: Also bear in mind that after phone restart all alarms are removed so you will need to register a broadcast receiver to be notified of the device boot-up so you can re-register any Alarms that are needed.

Comment: Thank you. Did you get around to writing that tutorial?

Comment: Shane - good response and the answer is no as I am buried in work still however I may write one since you have asked. Saying that there is a good tutorial for here http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and a [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

The AlarmManager will kick of your IntentService at specified intervals. You can kick off the IntentService for each set of actions.