# Is it possible to run a daily task on android without openning the app?

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I want to create an app that daily notifies me a value on a web page, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615600). It says that [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) will do the trick for the daily part but I am not sure if it is going to run when the app is closed.

By the way I found that if I want to run a job every 3 seconds the code will be the following:

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1,
            new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                    JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
builder.setPeriodic(3000);
```

If it is daily, should the time be:

```
builder.setPeriodic(86400000);
```

Or is there any way to Schedule at a exact time e.g. 9:00 a.m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your app has been force closed, any job scheduled with job scheduler will run even if the app is terminated.  If needed it will be restarted.  The only thing that will prevent it is if you declare the job not persistent and reboot the device.

Comment: what about the "setPeriodic" method. Is it the only way to schedule the job? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You can find example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Comment: JobScheduler is the newer version of AlarmManager with more power