# Android: How to check whether a week has passed using Calendar class

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I want to check if a week has passed (using `Calendar` Class) and if it has then I need to print a message.

```
int lastCallDate = Calendar.SATURDAY;

int day = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

if (day == lastCallDate + 7) {
    System.out.println("It's been a week");
} else { 
    System.out.println("It hasn't been a week");
}
```

Any suggestions or answers would be brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: you can achieve this by finding the day from the current date and then check it is sunday or not if sunday that means week had been passed.

Comment: A week since when? Since the last time you executed some task? Then you need to store the time you did that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running task periodicaly(once a day/once a week)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615543/running-task-periodicalyonce-a-day-once-a-week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (day %lastCallDate ==0){
        System.out.println("It's been a week");

} else {

         System.out.println("It hasn't been a week");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sari Masri, thanks for the answer! What does "%" do?

Comment: it will return Number of days left so if it the last day 7%7 will be zero

Comment: So assuming `day` is in the interval 1–7 inclusive, it’s technically the same as `if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY)`, only harder to decipher? (And if `lastCallDate` was `MONDAY`, that is, 2, the result would be completely nonsensical, I’m afraid.)

Comment: @OleV.V., thanks for the explanation! How would you do it?

Comment: @magicmass I’d either use the linked original question or like `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")).getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)`. With the reservation that I’m not sure I have understood the requirement from the question.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can store the first date as a UNIX timestamp. Then you can compare the current timestamp in seconds with the old, first saved timestamp whenever you want to check if 7 days past or not like below.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
long firstTimestampInSec = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

Then you can compare by looking if 604800 seconds past or not.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
long currentTimestampInSec = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
int oneWeekAsSec = 604800;

long firstTimestampInSec = getOldStoredTimestamp(); //First stored timestamp as seconds
if(currentTimestampInSec >= firstTimestampInSec + oneWeekAsSec){
    System.out.println("It's been a week");
}
else{
    System.out.println("It hasn't been a week");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Erdem Savasci, thanks for the answer. What’s “getOldStoredTimeStamp”? Where did you call it from?

Comment: Hi @magicmass. I just wrote it as an example. You can store the timestamp second value in many ways. For example in Android, you can use SharedPreferences as a key-value holder. Then you can write a method like "getOldStoredTimeStamp" to return the old timestamp value and compare it with the current value.